# Remove slash after <span> with css

Tags: html, css

I'm having a trouble with css trying to remove a text after < span> tag to append other text. how can i remove this

```
<p class="entry-meta">
   <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="">
      <a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author">
         <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span>
      </a> 
   </span> /  (this slash needs to be removed with css)</p>
```

Comment: CSS cannot remove/delete text, but it can hide text. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346446/2813224).

Answer (score 1):

```
<p class="replaced"><span>Original Text</span></p>
```

Using the CSS display property, you can hide the content inside the  tag, and then attach a pseudo-element with your new content to the

tag. You do not need to use absolute positioning here because display: none; completely removes the element from the page, and it does affect the layout. It’s as if the text inside the  element never existed.

**Here’s the CSS:**

```
.replaced span {
    display: none;
}

.replaced:after {
    content: "This text replaces the original.";
}
```

[For More INfo click here](https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/)

**HTML :**

```
 <p class="entry-meta replaced"><span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" 
       itemscope=""><a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author"> <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span></a> 
            </span><span class="ll">/  (this slash needs to be removed with css)</span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.ll {
    display: none;
}

.replaced:after {
    content: "This text replaces the original.";
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r8vv8so/7/)

Comment: can i display none overthere

Comment: yes  check the link i have given there is another example as well .

Comment: If it  solve you problem please accept the answer as well .

Comment: i didn't remove the / which is after span tag :(

Comment: please help Amitesh Kumar

Comment: i want after span end text remove

Comment: please check my answer now .

Answer (score 0):

just use this css lines:
.entry-meta { font-size: 0; } 
.entry-meta .entry-author { font-size: 12px !important; }

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot delete text, text must be deleted manually or programmatically by JavaScript. CSS is presentation so it can hide text. Off the top of my head there 4 ways to go about it and they all involve hiding the contents of `p.entry-meta` and revealing the contents of `span.entry-author`. The following demo has 4 Examples.

### Demo

```css
/* Example A - alpha/opacity */
.entry-metaA {color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
.entry-authorA {color:rgba(0,0,0,1)}
/**/

/* Example B - transparency */
.entry-metaB {color:transparent}
.entry-authorB {color:black}
/**/

/* Example C - font-size */
.entry-metaC {font-size:0}
.entry-authorC {font-size:16px}
/* Props to D.M. */

/* Example D - visible children elements */
.entry-metaD {visibility: hidden}
.entry-authorD {visibility: visible}
/**/
```

```html
<p class="entry-metaA">
   <span class="entry-authorA" itemprop="author" itemscope="">
      <a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author">
         <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span>
      </a> 
   </span> /  (this slash needs to be removed with css)
</p>
   
   
<p class="entry-metaB">
   <span class="entry-authorB" itemprop="author" itemscope="">
      <a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author">
         <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span>
      </a> 
   </span> /  (this slash needs to be removed with css)
</p>

<p class="entry-metaC">
   <span class="entry-authorC" itemprop="author" itemscope="">
      <a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author">
         <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span>
      </a> 
   </span> /  (this slash needs to be removed with css)
</p>

<p class="entry-metaD">
   <span class="entry-authorD" itemprop="author" itemscope="">
      <a href="#"class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author">
         <span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">yesi</span>
      </a> 
   </span> /  (this slash needs to be removed with css)
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

you mean you want to hide that text?

Then you can a class `.hideme {display: none;}`

If you wanna remove the text you need to do it with java script there are so many ways to do that.

Can you post the whole code with the ending `p` tag?

Comment: i also write over there

Comment: ok then just wrap the text in a class like <span class="hideme"> text I want to hide</span>